# Condition for every line through a line segment $S$ to be perpendicular to $S$?

Tags: geometry, foliations

In 3 dimensional space, given a line segment $S$ which has a line $l(0)$ passing through one endpoint at right angles and another, $l(1)$, passing through the other endpoint at right angles, such that $l(0)$ is not parallel to $l(1)$, prove that the lines passing through each point $l(x)$, $0<x<1$, will also be perpendicular to $S$ on the assumption that none of the lines through $S$ intersect. It is assumed that the $l(x)$, $0\le x \le 1$, are distributed continuously.

1. I believe I might have a counter example, but it's far from clear.
2. Note that this is true for a ruling line of the one-sheeted
   hyperboloid (or for those of a hyperbolic paraboloid) and its
   intersection of its dual ruling lines.
3. Of course, this condition
   could be weakened to the two end lines intersecting $S$ at any pair of congruent angles as long as their concave sides are facing the same directions.
4. If these conditions fail, are there stronger conditions which will
   make it work?

Comment: @MishaLavrov, No. this is in 3 dimensional space. I'm correcting my statement to make that clear.

Comment: In three dimensional space the statement fails.

Comment: In 3 dimensional space, $\ell(0)$ and $\ell(1)$ practically don't constrain $\ell(x)$ for $0<x<1$. For example if $S$ is the segment from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,0,0)$, we could have segments through $\ell(0)$ and $\ell(1)$ lie in the $(x,y)$-plane while the segments through $\ell(x)$ all lie in the $(x,z)$ plane, making any angle of your choice with $S$.

Comment: Yes. I succumbed to the fallacy that people can read my mind. I edited my statement. In any case, my statement in (3) was flat-out wrong and I've withdrawn it; thanks for the correction.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, if I add the condition of continuity, your objection about the case where $l(0)$ parallel to $l(1)$ seems to vanish.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample: suppose that the line segment is on the $x$-axis, starting at $(0,0,0)$ and ending at $(\pi,0,0)$. Let $\alpha(t) = \frac\pi4 + \frac12|t - \frac \pi2|$. Through the point $(t,0,0)$, draw the line with unit direction vector $(\sin \alpha(t), \cos t \cos \alpha(t), -\sin t \cos \alpha(t))$.

This vector is orthogonal to the vector $(0, \sin t, \cos t)$, as is the vector $(1,0,0)$, so the entire line we draw lies in the plane with equation $(x,y,z) \cdot (0, \sin t, \cos t) = 0$. As $t$ varies, these planes also vary, repeating with period $\pi$, and they only intersect on the $x$-axis. So as long $t_1 \not\equiv t_2 \pmod \pi$, the line through $(t_1,0,0)$ and the line through $(t_2,0,0)$ cannot intersect; they're skew.

This leaves us with complete freedom to choose the angle that the line makes with the $x$-axis, which we take advantage of: the angle is actually $\alpha(t)$. This is $\frac \pi2$ when $t=0$ or $t=\pi$, but not otherwise.

(I originally wanted to make $\alpha(t) = t + \frac\pi2$, which would be nicer, but the problem we run into is that $\alpha(t)$ should never be $0$. In that case, we end up drawing a line through the line segment, intersecting all the other lines. There's still probably a nicer choice of $\alpha(t)$.)